# XSLT Transformation within bash pass XPATH value to output file name

Tags: bash, xslt, xpath, saxon

I am doing a batch xsl transformation and want to use a parameter from my stylesheet to form the outputfile name, but I am rather unsure how to do that, it should be something like:

```
$output = Join-Path $mypath {{XPATH}} $file.Name
java -cp $saxonpath net.sf.saxon.Transform -t -s:$file -xsl:$xsltpath -o:$output
```

(with `{{XPATH}}` referring to my XPATH, something simple as `count(//error)`)

Hope someone can help me with that.z
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do XPath evaluation before running the XSLT to compute e.g. that count then call the XQuery processor with e.g.

```
java -cp $saxonpath net.sf.saxon.Query -qs:'count(//error)' -s:$file '!method=text'
```

e.g. to store that in a variable

```
count=`java -cp $saxonpath net.sf.saxon.Query -qs:'count(//*)' -s:$file '!method=text'`
```

or, in your original version, probably

```
$output = Join-Path $mypath `java -cp $saxonpath net.sf.saxon.Query -qs:'count(//*)' -s:$file '!method=text'` $file.Name
```

Comment: Great, thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining an output with `-o:$output`
You could pass your output path as a parameter to your tranformation and use `xsl:result-document` to create your output file.

Something along those lines :

```
$output = Join-Path $mypath $file.Name
java -cp $saxonpath net.sf.saxon.Transform -t -s:$file -xsl:$xsltpath -mypath=$output

<xsl:stylesheet>
  ...
  <xsl:param name="mypath"/>
  ...
  <xsl:result-document href="concat($mypath,count(//error))" method="xml">
    ...
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Depending on your system you need to be cautious of the separator used in your path.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that could be an option for me too, I'll guess I play with both alternatives.